# Runtime Error 3075 - - VBA Access- missing Operator

Tags: vba, ms-access

Where is the missing Operator?

**Code:**

```
If Nz(DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email=" & Me![Email]), "") <> "" Then
    correo = DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email=" & Me![Email])
```

Answer (score 0):

Email is going to be a string so your syntax should be:

```
If Nz(DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me.Email & "'"), "") <> "" Then
    correo = DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me.Email & "'")
```

Notice the single quotes added around the email address you are looking for.

Comment: @Negron can you update your original post with exactly what you have right now?  I have tested the above code and it runs with no problem in my system.

Comment: Private Sub ResetButton_Click()

Dim correo As String

If Nz(Me.Email, "") = "" Then
MsgBox "Email Empty. Please Enter a Valid Email Address.", vbInformation, "Email Empty"
Me.Email.SetFocus

Else
If Nz(DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me![Email]) & "'", "") <> "" Then
    correo = DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me![Email] & "'")


End If

If correo <> Me.Email Then
MsgBox "Wrong Email Address. Please Use a Correct Email Address.", vbCritical, "Wrong Email Address"
Me.Email.SetFocus
Else
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "UserVerificationPasswordReset"

End If
End If

End Sub

Comment: where Employees is a table and Email is a field

Comment: @Negron in your immediate windows Ctrl+G can you type `Msgbox DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '"Example@Domain.com'")` but put in a valid email and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Two things.  First, it's `ElseIf` in VBA, not `Else If` (no space).  Second, you have an extra `End If` at the end of the `If` block.  See below:

```
Private Sub ResetButton_Click()

    Dim correo As String

        If Nz(Me.Email, "") = "" Then
            MsgBox "Email Empty. Please Enter a Valid Email Address.", vbInformation, "Email Empty"
            Me.Email.SetFocus
        ElseIf Nz(DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me.Email & "'", "") <> "" Then
            correo = DLookup("Email", "Employees", "Email= '" & Me.Email & "'")
        End If

        If correo <> Me.Email Then
            MsgBox "Wrong Email Address. Please Use a Correct Email Address.", vbCritical, "Wrong Email Address"
            Me.Email.SetFocus
        Else
            DoCmd.Close
            DoCmd.OpenForm "UserVerificationPasswordReset"
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: He posted it in a comment.  Which has no return lines, now rewrite his code but go to another line where there is a space between Else If.  That will likely make a lot more sense.

Comment: I updated my answer, the references to the Email control were wrong.